# OpenCV: Save frame matrix to text file

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I have got a **USB-connected Webcam** and want to save the captured frame to a text file.

The frame is a **NumPy** array and I need to get only red color values.

So, here's my code:

```
vc = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

if vc.isOpened():
    rval, frame = vc.read()
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width = 640, height = 480)
    print(frame[..., ..., 2])
    savetxt('../test.txt', frame[..., ..., 2])
```

**print** gets me this:

> ```
> [[127 125 125 ..., 114 118 101]
>
>  [123 126 125 ..., 111 112 100]
>
>  [129 124 122 ..., 116 116 100]
>
>  ..., 
>
>  [121 120 121 ...,  97 104  88]
>
>  [118 121 121 ...,  96 103  90]
>
>  [116 122 120 ...,  97 105  90]]
> ```

But even if I could print the whole array, it does not fit the terminal window.

So I'd like to save it to a file but `savetxt()` function is not working as I want.

Here's the beginning of **test.txt**:

> 1.270000000000000000e+02 1.250000000000000000e+02 1.250000000000000000e+02

and so on.

I'm using `OpenCV 3.1` and `Python 2.7.12`

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`savetxt` default format is `'%.18e'` which explains the format you're getting.

```
numpy.savetxt(fname, X, fmt='%.18e', delimiter=' ', newline='\n', header='', footer='', comments='# ')[source]¶
```

Change the format specifier with `fmt` parameter to print integers instead of floats:

```
savetxt('../test.txt', frame[...,...,2],fmt="%d")
```